# Sudoedit configuration

Tags: rhel, hardening

I'm hardening a Rhel8.6, and I got this report "The sudoedit program must be used when edit privileges are required.." The directory reported is /etc/sudoers/*

How can I set sudoedit to be the only editor for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't. If someone is `root`, it is possible that `visudo`, `vi`, `ed` or even `emacs` is used.

There are possibilities.In the past, I had some experiences with `seos` and `autosecure` from Platinum. These suites used loadable modules (under AIX) or kernel modules to intercept system calls and do some additional authorization with it. The stuff has been acquired by CA and is now called eTrust. Haven't followed the CA acquisition, so you might want to do some investigation yourself. Be sure to ask for the (IMHO hefty) price of the license before you decide that this is what you want.